# laravel not redirecting, it is printing redirecting line message on my page

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-4

all were working fine but i don't what happened now

1. my login page,
2. when i click submit button it is showing me this error
   screen or msg

[image: My Login submit page]

3. come back again on the same login page.

Can anyone guide me, thanks.

**Updated:**

```
if (\Auth::attempt(array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password')), (Input::get('remember') == 1 ? true : false))) {
    return Redirect::to('_admin/dashboard')->with('message', 'You are now logged in!');
} else {
    return \Redirect::back()
        ->with('message', 'Your username/password combination was incorrect')
        ->withInput();
}
```

Comment: It is a little hard to comment without some code. When you hit 'submit' you should be redirected to /admin/dashboard, right?

Comment: yes, but it come back on /_admin/login again

Comment: @FBidu i have added a example code for you, but it is same for all/any redirects in the site.

Comment: Interesting... Is it possible that the code handling the `_admin/dashboard` is making some sort of redirect to the login page? What happens when you remove that `Redirect::to()` and put something like 'successful login'?

Comment: ** for quick fix, i wrote ob_start in the public/index.php file

Comment: yes, now it is working fine, i think there is something printing out before redirecting, isn't so?